# Drawing arrow on line using SLD of GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a line layer in geoserver as in the 1st image.

How can I draw an arrow on the line like in the 2nd image?

The line.rar includes a shapefile and a sld file.

Can edit a sample for me?

[**line.rar(download)**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Gy861SBrKyUktrV1ZzTXVvT1E/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The GeoServer documentations states how to extract start and end points with [geometry transformations](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/geometry-transformations.html?highlight=offset#start-and-end-point) (just use the end- point rule). The code example provided uses `square` as marks, but you could always replace this with e.g. the shape symbol [`shape://oarrow`](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html?highlight=svg#shape-symbols).

EDIT: I forgot to mention how to rotate the triangle correctly (couldn't find it in the documentation, but took it from [page 38 in this presentation](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/foss4g2011/gs_styling_aaime_foss4g2011.pdf))!

```
<Rotation>
<ogc:Function name="endAngle">
<ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
</ogc:Function>
</Rotation>
```

EDIT2: Just wanted to make sure everything works as described, here is a code sample based on GeoServer's default blue line SLD style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
        xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
        xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Blue arrows</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>A blue line with end arrows</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>Blue_Arrow_Line</Name>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Geometry>
                            <ogc:Function name="endPoint">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </Geometry>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>shape://oarrow</WellKnownName>
                                <Fill>
                                <CssParameter name="fill">#0000FF</CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
                                </Fill>
                                <Stroke>
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</CssParameter>
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
                                </Stroke>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>30</Size>
                            <Rotation>
                                <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                                </ogc:Function>
                            </Rotation>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

This is how it should look like:

[image: Blue Arrow Example image]

Comment: SAnderka, thanks a lot. I use the edit2 way and it runs wonderful on geoserver.

Comment: There is a grey checkmark underneath this question's voting buttons. You need to click it (it'll turn green) to mark your question as answered in GIS SE's system. Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work using CSS styles and cannot do it.  Can anyone help with that?  I though I was on to something with this but it does not work:

[@scale > 1] {
    geometry: startPoint(geom);
    mark:     symbol(triangle);
    mark-size:10px;
}

Comment: This may help if you're trying something like this in css:

`[@scale > 1] {
  mark-geometry: [startPoint(geom)];
  mark: symbol(arrow);
  mark-size:10px;
  mark-rotation: [endAngle(geom)];
  :mark {
    fill: white;
    stroke: black;
  }

}`