# Draw arrow in direction of line on midpoint in Geoserver SLD

Tags: geoserver, symbology, sld

Similar to this question: [How do I draw the arrow on the line using SLD of Geoserver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116712/how-do-i-draw-the-arrow-on-the-line-using-sld-of-geoserver)

The answer there works, but I need to place the arrow on the midpoint of the line. Alternatively, it could be placed along the line with a certain offset from the start or end point.

The reason is that I am using this for lines that have a symbolized point feature (for manholes in a sewer network) at each end. These points would interfere with arrow at beginning or end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

The filter functions currently available to align an arrow with a line are "startAngle" and "endAngle". What you need is a "midAngle" which is not there, but could be coded.

If you can code Java here are some references:

- [StartAngle source](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/function/FilterFunction_startAngle.java)
- [EndAngle source](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/function/FilterFunction_endAngle.java)
- [Their registration as plugins](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.opengis.filter.expression.Function#L67) (so that GeoTools/GeoServer can find them)
- [Code contribution directions](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)

If instead you'd like someone else to do the coding there is a [commercial support](http://geoserver.org/support/) option too.

Comment: Alternatively it needs a distance along the line function to allow offsets, but I guess that would end up being in pixels at that point

Comment: @IanTurton there was a fix on master to handle that (make sure these function work against the original geometry).