# Draw arrow on the line with Geoserver and Mongodb data

Tags: geoserver, mongodb

I'm looking for the guide to draw the arrow at end of line in geoserver.

So follow this thread ([How do I draw the arrow on the line using SLD of Geoserver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116712/how-do-i-draw-the-arrow-on-the-line-using-sld-of-geoserver)), I've made it work with the shapefile.

However, with my data source is from Mongodb, the arrow did not appear.
Here the sample of my Mongodb record.

```
{
"_id" : "Y6z5zsA6RF8Wpoocu",
"name" : "-1",
"description" : "",
"geometry" : {
    "type" : "LineString",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        [ 
            103.0102419455, 
            21.378932367
        ], 
        [ 
            103.0102432625, 
            21.3789060899
        ], 
        [ 
            103.0102144437, 
            21.3788595105
        ]
    ]
    },
}
```

If I choose generic style, the layer preview display ok. But when I change to the arrow style, the layer preview not work at all. So I added the 
    "properties" : {
        "the_geom" : ""
    },
    "the_geom" : ""
to make sure this part work, then the line appear again but without the arrow

```
<ogc:Function name="endPoint">
<ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
</ogc:Function>
```

It's seem that the < ogc:Function name="endPoint" > is not work with MongoDB source. When I remove that part the arrow appear but in the middle of the line.

How should I config with my data?

Comment: your geometry is called `geometry` not `the_geom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SLD you have asked GeoServer to find the endpoint of an attribute/property called `the_geom` (the default geometry name in a Shapefile), but in your MongoDB you have called your geometry element `geometry` so that nothing is found and the function (endPoint) returns a null geometry and thus nothing is drawn.