# Apply Point style in JMapFrame GUI

Tags: shapefile, java, sld, geotools

I've managed to create a Point shapefile creating a SimpleFeature and outputting it as **Test_Point.shp**,

```
public static final SimpleFeatureType POINT = createPointType(); 

private static SimpleFeature createPoint(){
    Coordinate start = CoordConverterUtils.getStart; 
    Coordinate end = CoordConverterUtils.getEnd;

    Coordinate mid = (new LineSegment(start,end)).midpoint()); 

    GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
    SimpleFeatureBuilder fb = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(POINT);
    Point p = gf.createPoint(mid); 
    fb.add(p);
    return fb.buildFeature(null); 
}


private static SimpleFeatureType createPointType(){
    try{
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("Point");
        builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
        builder.add("the_geom", Point.class);
        return builder.buildFeatureType(); 
    catch(Exception e){
        //warning 
        return null; 
    }
}
```

In the same directory I have a sld file **Test_Point.sld** that is from https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Point</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>SLD Cook Book: Simple Point</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Using Geotools - JMapFrame I can open/ view my Point shapefile, but can't seem to get the styling to be applied. Not sure if this is because

- The .sld is not done properly
- Geotools JMapFrame and filechooser can only open/ display .shp files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple Quickstart application can be modified to read a matching SLD file by adding the following dependancy:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-xsd-sld</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this code, which finds the basename, adds `.sld` and then loads it if it exists:

```
    // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("Quickstart");

    String basename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getAbsolutePath());
    File styleFile = new File(file.getParent(), basename + ".sld");
    System.out.println(styleFile);
    Style style;
    if(styleFile.exists()) {
      // create the parser with the sld configuration
      Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.sld.SLDConfiguration();
      Parser parser = new Parser(configuration);

      // the xml instance document above
      InputStream xml = new FileInputStream(styleFile);

      // parse
      StyledLayerDescriptor sld = (StyledLayerDescriptor) parser.parse(xml);
      style = SLD.styles(sld)[0];
    } else {
      style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
    }
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
    map.addLayer(layer);
```