# Drawing arrow on line using SLD of GeoServer - add an offset to the arrow head

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a style on GeoServer where lines have arrows at the end. I need to move arrow head back to make it end exactly on the line. Not after.

[image]

SLD style look style this:

I was trying too add an offset, but it doesn't work. Either because function clearly says "endPoin" or I was writing it incorrectly. I think it also can be resolved by another symbol, from  Wingdings or another library, but I can't find the one where center of the icon will be on the arrow top.

```
<Rule>
      <Name>rule 1</Name>
      <Title>Symbol = 1</Title>
      <Abstract>a single arrow (right side)</Abstract>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>symbol</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.1</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <PointSymbolizer>
                    <Geometry>
                        <ogc:Function name="endPoint">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </Geometry>
                    <Graphic>
                        <Mark>
                            <WellKnownName>ttf://Wingdings 3#0x0075</WellKnownName>
                            <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                            <Stroke>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                            </Stroke>
                        </Mark>
                        <Size>3</Size>
                        <Rotation>
                            <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </Rotation>
                    </Graphic>
                 </PointSymbolizer>          
    </Rule>     
    
    <Rule>
      <Name>rule 2</Name>
      <Title>Symbol = 3</Title>
      <Abstract>a single arrow (left side)</Abstract>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>symbol</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.1</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <PointSymbolizer>
                    <Geometry>
                        <ogc:Function name="endPoint">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </Geometry>
                    <Graphic>
                        <Mark>
                            <WellKnownName>shape://oarrow</WellKnownName>
                            <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                            <Stroke>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                            </Stroke>
                        </Mark>
                        <Size>3</Size>
                        <Rotation>
                            <ogc:Function name="startAngle">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </Rotation>
                    </Graphic>
                </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    
    <Rule>
      <Name>rule 3</Name>
      <Title>Symbol in nor equal 1 or 3 </Title>
      <Abstract>a double arrow</Abstract>
      <ogc:Filter>
        
        <ogc:And>
          
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>symbol</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
          
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>symbol</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        </ogc:And> 
        
      </ogc:Filter>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.1</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <PointSymbolizer>
                    <Geometry>
                        <ogc:Function name="endPoint">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </Geometry>
                    <Graphic>
                        <Mark>
                            <WellKnownName>shape://oarrow</WellKnownName>
                            <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                            <Stroke>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                            </Stroke>
                        </Mark>
                        <Size>3</Size>
                        <Rotation>
                            <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </Rotation>
                    </Graphic>
                </PointSymbolizer>
                <PointSymbolizer>
                    <Geometry>
                        <ogc:Function name="startPoint">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </Geometry>
                    <Graphic>
                        <Mark>
                            <WellKnownName>ttf://Wingdings 3#0x0074</WellKnownName>
                            <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                            <Stroke>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                            </Stroke>
                        </Mark>
                        <Size>3</Size>
                        <Rotation>
                            <ogc:Function name="startAngle">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </Rotation>
                    </Graphic>
                </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

I saw this question [Drawing arrow on line using SLD of GeoServer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116712/drawing-arrow-on-line-using-sld-of-geoserver) , but it doesn't cover my question about offset.

Can you help, please?

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use the `shape://oarrow` "well known mark" which does place itself at the end of the line.

[image]

Alternatively, there is an `AnchorPoint` element in Symbology Encoding
that can adjust your point.

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">

....
    <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>ttf://OpenSymbol#0x2227</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#060505</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#130101</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>15</se:Size>
          <se:Rotation>
            <ogc:Add>
            <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
              <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Add>
          </se:Rotation>
          <se:AnchorPoint>
            <se:AnchorPointX>0.5</se:AnchorPointX>
            <se:AnchorPointY>0.6</se:AnchorPointY>
            </se:AnchorPoint>
        </se:Graphic>
```

Ignore the 90 in the rotation, I didn't have windings so I used a vertical arrow from a maths font.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ian, shape://oarrow works perfectly for Function name="startPoint"! I forgot to say that I also have "endPoint". For lines with arrows from both sides. For endPoint it is placed incorrectly. Need the mirrored symbol.

Comment: Can you provide a complete SLD that shows the problem, there shouldn't be a difference between start and end points like that

Comment: Modified the description. Added all three rules. Right sided arrow, Left sided and lines with 2 arrows both sides.

Comment: Sorry, did you have a chance to check?

Comment: Sorry no, most of the GeoServer team are at the FOSS4G conference in Kosovo this week.

Comment: Wow, cool. I am trying to resolve this. The thing is that I need to place arrow at the end and start of the line. oarrow symbol works for "end". Documentation says: An open arrow symbol (triangle without one side, suitable for placing arrows at the end of lines). Need to mirror it for "start". arrows that I am currently using are Wingdings 3#0x0074 and Wend..75. They are pointed to different sides.

Comment: A start arrow should be exactly the same but at start angle